# isNaN alert is responding every time. Even when the value is number

Tags: javascript, html, alert, isnan

In my code I have an if statement, using an `isNaN()`. It is checking the input on a number field. If the input `isNaN()` (is not a number) it should throw and `alert()` Right now it's throwing that alert no matter what is input. Could you help? Thanks. Here's my code:

```js
const increaseValue = document.getElementById('positive');
const enter = document.getElementById('enter-value');

// input reception code

function useInput(){
    enter.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(isNaN(increaseValue)){
            alert("Your input was not a number! Try again.");
        }
    })
}
useInput();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FinanceTool.css">
    <title>Finance_Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
            <input type="number" id="positive" class="input" placeholder="Input financial increase." min="0"/>
            <button type="submit" id="enter-value">Enter</button>
    </main>
    <script src="FinanceTool.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('positive')` gives you a reference to the element, not the value it is currently holding. Use `document.getElementById('positive').value` to get the value of the input and it will work.

Comment: you have 2 problems, first, move this line inside your eventlistener `const increaseValue = document.getElementById('positive');`, you want to get the value entered after you press the button, not on page load when the input has no value. Second, use `.value` to get the actual value not the element

Comment: @ChrisG I really only see 1 problem. The script is loaded after the element exists, so it would also be fine to leave `const increaseValue = document.getElementById('positive');` outside the listener, and check `isNaN(increaseValue.value)` inside the listener.

Comment: Please don't modify your question in a way that invalidates an answer. Your last change invalidated the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an `<input type="number">` is an empty string if the value isn't a valid number, and `isNaN('')` returns `false`.

```js
console.log(isNaN(''));
```

But the input also has a property `valueAsNumber` that returns `NaN` for invalid input:

```js
const increaseValue = document.getElementById('positive');
const enter = document.getElementById('enter-value');

// input reception code

function useInput(){
    enter.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(increaseValue.valueAsNumber);
        console.log(increaseValue.value);
        if(isNaN(increaseValue.valueAsNumber)){
            alert("Your input was not a number! Try again.");
        }
    })
}
useInput();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FinanceTool.css">
    <title>Finance_Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
            <input type="number" id="positive" class="input" placeholder="Input financial increase." min="0"/>
            <button type="submit" id="enter-value">Enter</button>
    </main>
    <script src="FinanceTool.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```